# TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X' in sklearn KMeans

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import warnings
import graphviz
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
%matplotlib inline
import os
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

#Importing the dataset
Diabetes2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\PPP\\Desktop\\Python_Practice\\Datasets\\Diabetes\\diabetic_data.csv', index_col=False)

#Split into input and output features
y = Diabetes2["readmittedFL"]
X = Diabetes2[["time_in_hospital","num_lab_procedures","num_procedures","num_medications",
               "number_outpatient","number_emergency","number_inpatient","number_diagnoses"]]
X.head()
y.head()

#Select the annual income and the spending score columns 
KMeans = KMeans()
X_array=X.iloc[0:8:1].values
y_kmeans = KMeans.predict(X_array)
plt.scatter(X_array[:, 0], X_array[:, 1], c=y_kmeans, s=50, cmap='viridis')
```

I just started practicing KMeans where I am getting this error. I can not understand what is wrong.

When I run the command `y_kmeans = KMeans.predict(X_array)`,
it was showing an error
`TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: X`

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need yo use `fit_predict` not `predict`

- fit_predict : Train and predict your train point cluster
- Predict:  used for inference when you get new data points that are
  not present on your train data

Also your not specifying the number of clusters via `n_clusters` argument it will take default number which is 8

for more info check this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)